# Seo, pagerank - query in url

Tags: search, seo, search-engine

I have a question about pagerank.

I want to know, if google counting different pagerank for these URLs, or if the query presence in url never mind and pagerank of these url will be counted as one only for "site.com/dir/":

```
a) site.com/dir/
b) site.com/dir/?q=875445
c) site.com/dir/?q=adssda
```

or

```
a) site.com/dir/index.php
b) site.com/dir/index.php?q=875445
c) site.com/dir/index.php?q=adssda
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google gives ranks to pages e.g

```
a) site.com/dir/
b) site.com/dir/?q=875445
c) site.com/dir/?q=adssda

a = page, b = different page, c = another different page
```

if you want to check ranks for pages on the go

you can download an extension for google chrome called SEOquake it lets you see all kinds of stuff for the current page that you are looking at.

SO it doesn't matter how your pages URL are like,if it's a different page than it's a different page e.g different page rank